# SQL Server Reporting Server (SSRS) separation of dev, stg, and prd data

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, ssrs-2016

I have a single SSRS server available to me (it's a HA cluster) and am looking for a solution to logically separate dev/stg/prd data that isn't too burdensome to maintain. There is no option to stand up another server or use VMs.

One of the original ideas was to use schemas, but I think this would require a set of queries customized for each environment. Ideally, changing the pointer between instances (e.g., from stg to prd) would be quick. For example, if I could just change the connection string without modifying anything else. So, maybe we need to set up additional databases if SSRS supports this. I'm struggling a bit to articulate this point, and I may not even be on the right track.

Also, I'm a guy that sometimes works with databases and has a working knowledge (hopefully) of MS SQL/SQL, but I do not have the expertise that comes with time.

Comment: Not fully clear. Are you trying to main 3 separate environments for the SSRS database / website itself? Or 3 separate environments for your actual user data?

Comment: The goal was to achieve some separation between dev, stg, and prd to avoid cross-contamination of data, screwing up prd with development work, etc... It looks like the way to do this with SSRS (on the same server) is to run the installation again and create a new instance...which creates a new DB and so on. My vote would be for completely separate servers, but that wasn't an option :(

Comment: Ok, so you're not talking about your user databases with all your data. You mean the actual SSRS application databases, e.g. `ReportServer` and `ReportServerTemp`?

Answer (score 1):

The most common solution for DEV/STAGE/PRODUCTION is to have three servers. This way you will have three databases with the same name, and you can just copy them from one server to another. For example to make a Stage data you can do:

- backup db from PROD
- restore it to STG
- update tables with sensitive data (i.e. `update people set ssn='123-45-6789`)
- done.

Three databases on the same server is also possible. But it will not work if your business requires several databases. For example, if your ETL by itself requires a staging area - you will eventually have issues of mistaking between database groups (DEV/STG/PROD). Another huge problem is that you can want to play with server settings and if you have DEV and PROD on the same server...

Splitting by schema - absolutely no. A user would have to run `select * from dev.tbl` or `select * from prod.tbl` - and to switch from one environment to another that user would have to change a query. And what if you put that query into a client application?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to have multiple environments that store data in a single SQL Server database engine instance, create a separate database for each environment.

Separate databases is simpler to maintain than separate schemas, as all Dev and DevOps tools understand how to work with databases, and the data and security separation is simpler and more robust.

If you have separate SSRS environments that share a single server, use folders.